# How to refresh reference to objects in Visual Studio SSDT?

Tags: ssdt

I have an issue related to missing reference to tables or views which exist in Visual Studio SSDT. For example I have two SSDT projects. One for database X second for database Y. In project X I've created a reference to database Y and a stored procedures to tables from project Y. Everything worked well till last time I've created next table "abc" in Project Y. Now when I'm trying to create a stored procedure in Project X with this "abc" table from Project Y I cannot resolve its name. On the dropdown list in the Project X (FROM clause) I can see all tables from project Y except the last one and I get the blue underscore and unresolved reference warining.

Is there a way to refresh this dropdown list with tables somehow (maybe similar like I'm refreshing IntelliSense cache in SSMS ?

[image]

Comment: Did you try building Project Y?

Comment: Yes, build completed without errors. Only warnings that Project X has unresolved reference to Project Y tables.

Comment: Did you create a Project reference or a direct reference to a dacpac you built previously? Maybe your reference is out of date

Comment: I've created database reference "TEST" in the "A" SSDT project - like on the picture attached above. And next when I add new object (eg. table or view) to the TEST database it is not visible (it is not resolved) in "A" SSDT project and there is a message "unresolved reference". Thats way I've asked this question because maybe there is a way to refres object list for particular database reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've find out the answer for my question. One man had similar case and put it on MSDN. And Microsoft answer was that Visual Studio will not implement Visual Studio SSDT InteliSense reference refreshment feature. The workaround they've proposed is to remove and recreate the "database reference" in particular SSDT project. So I've removed old database reference and next create it back again. After such modification InteliSense drop-down list for references for TSQL code has been refreshed and works well. So when you add new objects to the referenced database you have to remove and create again database reference to be able to see newly created objects in InteliSense drop-down list when coding.